# Allow multiple selection in a dialogue field

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

Is it possible to allow multiple selection in a dialogField, in the same way that report selection criteria fields work?

So for example, I have a dialogField which has extended type InventSiteId, each time I select an inventSiteId from the drop down I would like the lookup added to my dialogField, rather than replace it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using the `ReplaceOnLookup` attribute which is available on `StringEdit` controls.

```
DialogField dlgField = dialog.addField(...);
FormStringControl fsc = dlgField.control();
fsc.replaceOnLookup(false);
```

Comment: this is great, however because I am using dialogInventSiteId = dialog.addFieldValue(typeid(InventSiteId),siteId, "Site"); to set the dialog, I am limited to 10 characters, can I increase this limit?

Comment: You will have to make new EDT, say InventSiteRange extending Range using same lookup as InventSiteId. In this case an old fashion reference on the ETD will do (the value in the dialog is not validated).